# When is it appropriate to use "titled" vs. "entitled"?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

When is it appropriate to use "titled" vs. "entitled"?  For example, which is the correct word to use in the following sentence?

> I really liked the conclusion to
>   rands’ latest blog post entitled “How
>   to Run a Meeting”.

Answer (score 6):

From the *NOAD*:

> titled /ˈtaɪdld/
>   adjective
>   (of a person) having a title indicating high social or official rank.
>
> entitle /ɪnˈtaɪdl/ /ɛnˈtaɪdl/
>   verb [trans.] (usually be entitled)
>   1. give (someone) a legal right or a just claim to receive or do something: *employees are normally entitled to severance pay* | [trans.] *the landlord is entitled to require references*.
>   2. give (something, especially a text or work of art) a particular title: *an article entitled "The Harried Society."*
>    - [trans.] archaic give (someone) a specified title expressing their rank, office, or character: *they entitled him Sultan*.

In your example, you should say *I really liked the conclusion to rands' latest blog post entitled "How to Run a Meeting."*

Comment: I think NAOD has it right but what is missing is the active voice. To say something was 'entitled' as opposed to 'titled' is, as the NAOD points out archaic. IE: "I was looking at the painting titled 'Dejuener sur l'herbe'" vs  "I was looking at the painting entitled 'Dejuener sur l'herbe'". Neither one is particularly right/wrong, but the latter is confusing.

Comment: @mfg: Only the second meaning (to give someone a title) is reported to be archaic.

Comment: right, but the first example does not pertain to the title of the blog entry; the usage of the second definition is what the post is asking about.

Comment: @mfg: That is 2.2; the OP is referring to 2.1, the one with _an article entitled "The Harried Society."_ as example.

Answer (score 6):

The verbs *entitle* and *title* are synonyms. Regarding nouns, *title* is a noun, *entitle* is not. *Title* on its own is an adjective (the title story - the story from the book the book got its title from), *entitle* is not. *Entitle* has an additional association to the meaning of having rights to or honor: I was *entitled* to the deduction.

The verb *entitle* regards the given name as a more distinguished feature of an object, more than the verb *title*.

When you say

> The book is titled "Far away from here".

you are saying that technically it has that title, but when you say

> The book is entitled "Far away from here".

you are implying some sort of preference, either that you liked the book, or that the title was appropriate, or that the book has become famous, or that you want to suggest people to read it, something that gives to the book more than just a simple title.

> I entitle this book with her name.

means *I am giving this book something special by giving it a title of more importance to me*, suggesting strong emotions.

> The director wanted to title the movie "Loud air".

means what it says. In this sentence using *entitle* instead of *title* would be kind of strange, unless something more is said about the movie or the director.

In your sentence "I really liked..." suggests preference, honor, and, although *titled* and *entitled* are both correct, *entitled* suggests "appropriately titled" or "nicely titled" which is what the author really wanted to express.

Answer (score 2):

There is an interesting article on this topic at the following URL. It provides usage statistics. http://grammarist.com/usage/entitled-titled/

Comment: Hello and welcome! Please see [how to answer questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer), specifically: Provide context for links. Always quote or summarize the key points that you're linking to.

Answer (score 1):

"Titled", I believe, typically refers to title as in [rank or nobility](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/titled). "Entitled" [means](http://www.merriam-webster.com/netdict/entitled) (for one) "to give a title to" or designate.

Comment: *Entitled*: To have a right to do something

Answer (score 1):

"Entitled" would denote a usage whereby one is deserving of, as opposed to "Titled" where someone is already honored. "Entitled", when used to refer to how something is titled, is just confusing usage. Using "the article was titled ... " is more concise.

Comment: Another usage for 'entitled' is in the sense of 'entitled to', or 'entitlements'; one might use entitled like this "I am entitled to my retirement benefits." which brings about another layer of confusion with using 'entitled.' 

It seems that a more accurate signal phrase would use a more current word (esp in MLA/APA citations).

Answer (score 1):

According to dictionary.com, 'title' as a verb means "to furnish with a title; designate by an appellation; entitle."  I conclude both are acceptable.  I think I tend to use 'titled' preferentially, probably because it's shorter.