# Is the "en-" verb prefix redundant?

Tags: prefixes

The verb prefix *en-* seems redundant to me. For example

- a book titled 'Something'
- a book entitled 'Something'

Are these identical in meaning, or is there some nuance?

Comment: ***Entitled vs. titled*** : *When they are synonymous with named or called, there is no substantive difference between entitled and titled. Some people object to this use entitled, but the objection is baseless. The use of entitled to mean named goes back centuries, and entitled was in fact the preferred term until recently. Google Books uncovers only 23 instances of the phrase “book titled” in works published in the 19th century, against some 31,000 instances of “book entitled.” (Titled in those days was much more often used to mean having a noble title.)* (The Grammarist)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is it appropriate to use "titled" vs. "entitled"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1390/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-titled-vs-entitled) (the specific question; the general question is too broad). There is also a lack of research shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes *en-* is redundant, and sometimes not. Also, redundancy is not always a bad thing.

There are fairly large differences in meaning between *force(d)* and *enforce(d),* *treat(ed)* and *entreat(ed),* *trust(ed)* and *entrust(ed),* *fold(ed)* and *enfold(ed).*

There is a previous question about the usage of *title(d)* and *entitle(d)* that you may want to look at: [When is it appropriate to use "titled" vs. "entitled"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1390/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-titled-vs-entitled) In the context of your example, either could be used with no difference in meaning.